# Cartesian Product - Functions

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I'm comfortable determining whether a function is onto, one-to-one, neither or both with single variables such as $f(x)$.

I'm a bit stumped when cartesian products and two variables are thrown into the mix. I don't quite get how something like the below would be determined.

\begin{align}
f\colon \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} &\to \mathbb{Z} × \mathbb{Z}\\
 (x,y) &\mapsto (x+1,2y)
\end{align}

What would this translate to in plain English or a real world example?

Comment: Just substitute your favorite integers in place of $x$ and $y$. Btw, $f$ increases the first coordinate by one, while doubles the second coordinate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In (more or less) plain English that is a function that takes as input a pair of integers and produces another pair as output. If you think of the variables as real numbers rather than just integers it maps the coordinate plane to itself. For example, the origin $(0,0)$ goes to the point $(1,0)$.

When thinking formally, every function is a function of a "single variable". In this case the variable happens to be a pair of numbers.

Don't be confused by the fact that the domain and codomain are ordered pairs with the way to describe a function as a set of ordered pairs. In this example the pair
$$
((0,0),(1,0)) \in (\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}) \times ( \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z})
$$
is a member of $f$. But you will hardly ever think that way.

Whether this is a "real world" example is more a philosophical question than a mathematical one. I suppose you could think of it as describing how a frog hops from one point to another.

Comment: That definitely clarifies it more. So the way I'm thinking about this is that this function is one-to-one but not onto because there isn't an (x,y) where (1,1) is the output, since the set Z of integers does not include 0. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: It is one-to-one but not onto, as you assert. The reason you give for showing it's not onto is wrong. $0$ is an integer. But $(1.1)$ is not in the range for a different reason ...

Comment: I see where I went wrong, I mixed up the fact that 0 is neither in \mathbb{Z}^+ or \mathbb{Z}^-. For (1,1), there isn't a y that would be multiplied by 2 to give 1.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken linear algebra ? Your example is sort of the same as (linear) functions $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$, but instead, the inputs and outputs lie on the nodes of the lattice $\mathbb{Z}^2$.